# How to add the x intercept from geom_vline in density plot as a label?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a density plot and facet it.
Let's say I have 4 groups for a variable, faceting it using this variable will generate me with 4 density plots.

For each density plot, I put in a vertical line which represents the mean.

However one needs to eyeball and look at the intersection between x-axis and the vertical line to see roughly how much is the mean.

What I want to create is for each density plot, I also want to show its mean as a label in the plotting area.

Below example code

```
x <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 1)
y <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 20, sd = 1)
z <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 40, sd = 1)



df <- as_tibble(cbind(
  c(x,y,z), 
  c(rep('x',length(x)), rep('y',length(y)), rep('z',length(z))),
  c(rep('a',length(x)/2), rep('b',length(x)/2))))

df$V1 <- as.numeric(df$V1)

df <- df %>% group_by(V2, V3) %>%
  summarise(mumean = mean(V1)) %>%
  right_join(df)


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = V1, color = V2)) + 
  geom_density(aes(fill = V2)) + facet_grid(V3 ~ V2) + theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(data = df, aes(xintercept = mumean))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to pre-calc the means and use those to feed `geom_vline` and `geom_text`:

```
library(dplyr)
iris_means <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(Sepal.Length))

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_density() +
  geom_vline(data = iris_means, aes(xintercept = mean)) +
  geom_text(data = iris_means, aes(x = mean, label = mean), 
             y = 0.1, angle = 90, vjust = -0.2) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome :). Just a bit tangent, any tips to vary the 'y' in geom_text so that it automatically fits itself nicely? My actual data has another variable which I need to loop over. However they have different density. If I use a fix 'y', sometimes it would be positioned too high or too low..

Comment: There's probably a `ggrepel` solution for that, but I'm not sure an elegant way to make the text repel specifically from the density plot edges.